# Search including special characters in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-compass, mongodb-atlas-search

I faced with the issue when I try to search for several words including a special character (section sign "§").
**Example**: AB § 32.
I want all words "AB", "32" and symbol "§" to be included in found documents.
In some cases document can be found, in some not.
If my document contains the following text then search finds it:
`Lagrum: 32 § 1 mom. första stycket a) kommunalskattelagen (1928:370) AB`

But if document contains this text then search doesn't find:
`Lagrum: 32 § 1 mom. första stycket AB`

For symbol "§" I use UT8-encoding "\xc2\xa7".

Index uses "lucene.swedish" analyzer.

```
      "Content": [
        {
          "analyzer": "lucene.swedish",
          "minGrams": 4,
          "tokenization": "nGram",
          "type": "autocomplete"
        },
        {
          "analyzer": "lucene.swedish",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
```

Query looks like:

```
{
    "index": "test_index",
    "compound": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "text": {
                    "query": [
                        "111111111111"
                    ],
                    "path": "ProductId"
                }
            },
        ],
        "must": [
            {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "query": [
                        "AB"
                    ],
                    "path": "Content"
                }
            },
            {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "query": [
                        "\xc2\xa7",
                    ],
                    "path": "Content"
                }
            },
            {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "query": [
                        "32"
                    ],
                    "path": "Content"
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    "count": {
        "type": "lowerBound",
        "threshold": 500
    }
}
```

The question is what is wrong with the search and how can I get a correct result (return both above mentioned documents) ?

Answer (score 0):

Focusing only on the `content` field, here is an index definition that should work for your requirements. The docs are [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/define-field-mappings/#std-label-bson-data-types-autocomplete). Let me know if this works for you.

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "autocomplete",
          "tokenization": "nGram",
          "minGrams": 4,
          "maxGrams": 7,
          "foldDiacritics": false,
          "analyzer": "lucene.whitespace"
        },
        {
          "analyzer": "lucene.swedish",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the analyzer to keyword for both options to search for special characters

Comment: Can you please explain **how** to do that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: go to mongo atlas search, create an index, name the index, than click refine settings

go down choose a custom analyzer, choose tokenizer as keyword, tokenFilters lowercase

in the search query , use compound statement with wild card operator to search at start or mid or end.